# Sort List<List<string>> by a certain 'column'

Tags: c#, linq

Example input and current output with out sorting:

```
List<List<string>> _optoGrid = new List<List<string>>();

_optoGrid.Add(new List<string>() {"10",     "10",     "100",    "20",    "10",     "10"});
_optoGrid.Add(new List<string>() {"20",     "20",     "50",     "10",    "1546",   "555"});
_optoGrid.Add(new List<string>() {"30",     "30",     "10",     "10",    "10",     "100"});
_optoGrid.Add(new List<string>() {"30",     "30",     "10",     "1",     "10",     "100"});
```

display this is where the sort code would go.

```
foreach (List<string> list in _optoGrid)
{
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        Console.Write(s + ", ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Current Output:

> 10, 10, 100, 20, 10, 10,
>
> 20, 20, 50, 10, 1546, 555,
>
> 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 100,
>
> 30, 30, 10, 1, 10, 100,

Desired Output assuming sort by column 5 (starting at 0):

> 20, 20, 50, 10, 1546, 555,
>
> 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 100,
>
> 30, 30, 10, 1, 10, 100,
>
> 10, 10, 100, 20, 10, 10,

in my head I would like to type:

```
_optogrid.Sort(5) //5 being the 'column' number
```

Comment: Use `OrderBy`, not `Sort`

Comment: There's no `column` in `List<T>`... maybe index you are looking for?

Comment: yeah that why i have column in quotes just cause i an trying to treat it as such

Comment: @user3755946 that's very fragile code.What happens if you *forget* one value? What if there's an extra value? If all nested lists have the same number of items why not use a proper class instead of a list?

Comment: Using strings means that lexicographical ordering will be used too, and `"1000"` will come before `"555"` or even `"5"`. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code has no columns, it's a list that contains lists. LINQ can still order the results. The methods that order results in LINQ are `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()`. Its argument is a lambda that produces the ordering key.

In this case, the lambda should return the list item that should be used for ordering, eg :

```
var  _optoGrid = new List<List<string>>{
    new List<string> {"10",     "10",     "100",     "20",    "10",     "10"},
    new List<string> {"20",     "20",     "50",     "10",     "1546",   "555"},
    new List<string> {"30",     "30",     "10",     "10",     "10",     "100"},
    new List<string> {"30",     "30",     "10",     "1",     "10",     "100"}
};
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderBy(lst=>lst[5]);
```

Or

```
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderByDescending(lst=>lst[5]);
```

That's very fragile code though. Nothing guarantees that all lists have the same number of items. It's very easy to forget one value or enter one more. `.OrderBy(lst=>lst[5])` will throw if one list contains fewer than 6 items but won't complain if the *wrong* number of items are used.

It would be better if a proper class was used instead of lists, especially if all items are expected to have the same number of items, eg :

```
class MyItem
{
    public string ProperlyNamedProperty1{get;set;}
    ...
    public MyItem(string prop1,string prop2,...)
    {
        ProperlyNamedProperty1=prop1;
        ...
    }
}

var  _optoGrid = new List<MyItem>{
    new MyItem("10",     "10",     "100",     "20",    "10",     "10"),
};
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderBy(item=>item.Property6);
```

Value tuples can also be used if the list is only going to be used locally, eg in a single method. Of course, 6 properties are a bit too much :

```
var  _optoGrid = new List<(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5, string prop6)>{
    ("10",     "10",     "100",     "20",    "10",     "10"),
    ("20",     "20",     "50",     "10",     "1546",   "555"),
    ("30",     "30",     "10",     "10",     "10",     "100"),
    ("30",     "30",     "10",     "1",     "10",     "100")
};
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderBy(tuple=>tuple.prop6);
```

If one is feeling very lazy and the number of items isn't that greate, the names can be ommited:

```
var  _optoGrid = new List<(string, string, string, string, string, string)>{
    ("10",     "10",     "100",     "20",    "10",     "10"),
    ("20",     "20",     "50",     "10",     "1546",   "555"),
    ("30",     "30",     "10",     "10",     "10",     "100"),
    ("30",     "30",     "10",     "1",     "10",     "100")
};
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderBy(tuple=>tuple.Item6);
```

The nice thing about tuples is they are strongly typed. There's no reason to use the same type for all of them, eg :

```
var  _optoGrid = new List<(int, int, string, string, string, double)>{
    (10,     10,     "100",     "20",    "10",    10),
    (20,     20,     "50",     "10",     "1546",  555),
    (30,     30,     "10",     "10",     "10",    100),
    (30,     30,     "10",     "1",     "10",     100)
};
var orderedResults=_optoGrid.OrderBy(tuple=>tuple.Item6);
```

This avoids another thorny issue, that of lexicographical ordering. If I change a string from `"10"` to `"1000" it will *still* appear before "555", because words that start with`"1"`always come before words that start with`"5". Using strings, `OrderBy` will return :

```
10 10 100 20 10   10000 
20 20 50  10 1546 555
```

Ooops.

Using an `int` or `double` for the sixth field though, we get the expected order :

```
20 20  50 10 1546   555 
10 10 100 20   10 10000
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `OrderByDescending` (looking at the expected output)

Comment: yes i used order by descending I will accept this as the answer once changed,   I know its fragile it's only a short term solution to act on a List<List<string>> that is always a consistent size.  Thankyou

Comment: @user3755946 even for a short term it's too fragile to be worth it. I posted a few options to fix this. Even the raw tuple option (the last one) guarantees that the correct number of items and the correct type are used

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos I see you point... thank for the complete answer I was contemplating pulling the query straight into a data-grid view (as it come from a sql query) should i do this or still use one of your solutions?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just tried this getting odd results... 20,20,50,10,1590555,
10,10,100,20,5410,
30,30,10,10,54100,
30,30,10,1,54100,

Comment: @user3755946 if you tried `OrderByDescending` using the fifth column as key there's nothing strange. 3 rows have the same order key so they'll appear all together in no specific order. If you want to order using more values as a key, return them in the lambda, eg `OrderByDescending(item=> new {item.Item5,item.Item2})`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like sorting a table by a certain column number.

`Enumerable.OrderBy` will do the job.

Enumerable.OrderBy, that takes a sequence of `TRow` items, and a keySelector. A keySelector  is a function that takes a `TRow` as input and returns a value on which the sequence must be ordered.

In your case, a `TRow` is a `List<string>`. So if you need to order by the column with index `sortColumnIndex` you need a KeySelector that takes a `List<String> row` and returns `row[sortColumnIndex]`

How about this:

int sortColumnIndex = 5;   // order by column 5
   List> unorderedList = ...
   List orderedList = unorderedList.OrderBy(row => row[sortColumnIndex]);

Simple comme bonjour!